# Exportar datos en laravel usando MaatWebsiteExcel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-excel

tengo una función en un controlador que exporta los datos a excel mediante dos parámetros que recibo que son un intervalo de fechas, los paramétros los recibo bien desde la vista en blade pero no consigo pasarlos al "Export", para ello tengo este código

**Fichero EncuestasExport.php**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Exports;

 use App\Encuesta;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

 class EncuestasExport implements FromCollection
 {
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return Encuesta::all();
    }
}
```

Luego tengo la función del controlador encargada de hacer la exportación

```
public function exportExcelFile($fecha_ini , $fecha_fin)
{

    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();

    $encuestas = Encuesta::where('fecha', '>=', $fecha_ini)->take(1);
    return Excel::download( new EncuestasExport($encuestas), 'encuestas.xls');

}
```

Me devuelve el excel pero con todas los elementos "encuestas" me devuelve unas 10000, por lo tanto ni me hace la condición del where, ni el "take(1)"

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Puedes inyectar datos a través del constructor del objeto de exportación o agregar setters para los datos que deseas pasar, pero en lo que muestras no estás usando ninguna de esas opciones. Dices "Me devuelve el excel pero con todas los elementos encuestas" y sí, es lo que le indicas que haga con `return Encuesta::all();`. Luego dices "por lo tanto ni me hace la condición del where, ni el "take(1)" y no es así, esa consulta la estás haciendo en el controlador, no en la clase EncuestasExport.

Answer (score 0):

Adjunto la solución, gracias al compañero @porloscerros he visto la luz.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Encuesta;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;

class EncuestasExport implements FromQuery , WithHeadings , WithMapping
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct(string $fechaInicio, string $fechaFin)
    {
        $this->fechaInicio = $fechaInicio;
        $this->fechaFin = $fechaFin;

    }

    public function query()
    {
        return Encuesta::query()
            ->where('fecha','>=',$this->fechaInicio);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'ID',
            'Tipo',
            'Nombre',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $row
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function map($row): array
    {
        $fecha = Carbon::parse($row->fecha)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');

        return [
            $row->id,
            $row->tipo,
            $row->nombre
        ];
    }


}
```

Comment: pero como recibio los parámetros en excel?¿ porfa inserta el código del controlador y de la vista